# How to submit fields other than model fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to write a view that returns the model plus additional fields that is not part of the model.

In the controller I should access these like:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @stuff = params[:stuff]
```

How can I write the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `fields_for` helper

```
form_for @post do |f|
    f.text_field :title
    fields_for :stuff do |stuff_form|
      stuff_form.text_field :name    
    end
end
```

remember, its simply `fields_for` not `f.fields_for`. if you use `f.fields_for` it will give the stuff_form fields as part of your `post` object params

Answer (score 1):

Use [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), thus:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :stuff %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

For most types of input field, there's both the `f.field_type` and `field_type_tag` helpers. The former are for fields that are part of the model, whereas the latter are simply additional fields that will be present in the `params`. So the above would give you a params hash like this:

```
{:post => {:title => 'the title', :body => 'the contents of the post'}, :stuff => 'contents of stuff field'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add field tags that are not part of your form which will add to the params hash.

in haml...

```
= text_field_tag :stuff, "what you want in stuff"
= hidden_field_tag :stuff, "or if you wanted a hidden field to show stuff"
```

will result in params hash...

```
stuff=>"what you want in stuff"
```